# phase assignment in an OFDM signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, spectrum, software-defined-radio

I have an OFDM signal which is giving me half the power spectrum (half the bandwidth) I am meant to have. I am been told the phase assignment is what is causing it but I have been twitching on it for days.... still not having the right answer

```
prp=1e-6;   
fstep=1/prp;   
M = 4;                                 %   QPSK signal constellation   
k = log2(M);                           %  bits per symbol    
fs=4e9;  
Ns=floor(prp*fs);   
no_of_data_points = (Ns/2);            
no_of_points=no_of_data_points;

no_of_ifft_points = (Ns);            %   256 points for the FFT/IFFT  
no_of_fft_points = (Ns);   
nsamp = 1;                          % Oversampling rate   


fl = 0.5e9;   
fu = 1.5e9;     

 Nf=(fu-fl)/fstep;       
phin=zeros(Nf,1);          

dataIn = randint(no_of_data_points*k*2,1,2);  % Generate vector of binary            
data_source = randsrc(1, no_of_data_points*k*2, 0:M-1);
qpsk_modulated_data= modulate(modem.qammod(M),data_source);     
modu_data= qpsk_modulated_data(:)/sqrt(2);           
[theta, rho] = cart2pol(real(modu_data), imag(modu_data));       
A=angle(modu_data);       
theta=radtodeg(theta);        

figure(3);       
plot(modu_data,'o');%plot constellation without noise       
axis([-2 2 -2 2]);      
grid on;       
xlabel('real'); ylabel('imag');       

%%   E:GENERTION        
phin = zeros(Nf,1);      

phin(1:Nf,1)=theta(1:Nf);      



 No = fl/fstep;       

Vn = zeros(Ns,1);       
for r = 1:Nf        
 Vn(r+No,1) = 1*phin(r,1);       
% Vn(r+No,2) = 1*phin(r,2);      
 end       

%%
%------------------------------------------------------     
 %E.     Serial to parallel conversion      
%------------------------------------------------------      

par_data = reshape(Vn,2,no_of_data_points);     

 %%     
 % F.     IFFT Transform each period's spectrum (represented by a row of             
 % time domain via IFFT      


time_domain_matrix =ifft(par_data.',Ns);
```

Comment: you should tell us where you observe your spectrum; I don't see that in your matlab code, and it's quite probable the problem is in the way you look at your signal, not in the signal itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are only considering the real part of the signal.